# Error SQL71501: Table: [schemaname].[tablename] has an unresolved reference to Schema [schemaname]

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, azure-synapse

I need some help, I am creating a new DB project in visual studio 2015 and imported a create table SQL script. This table script is an Azure SQL dw table which has schema name and table name with columns. A file with schema name was created under the DB project and a script for the table is created.

My aim is to keep the script in a solution which can be used later for changes, and the table should be created in another Azure SQL DW database. Could you please let me know how to achieve this. I have gone to many docs and I didn't find any solution. When I am trying to build the project I am facing the issue

> Error SQL71501: Table: [schemaname].[tablename] has an unresolved
>   reference to Schema [schemaname].

Answer (score 4):

Try running a schema comparison from the DB to your project and see if it suggests creating or making changes to any schemas. Also make sure that the schema file is included in the build (Properties -> Build Action = 'Build').

Comment: Setting the build action to 'Build' worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create the Schema for that table to be created in that schema. Otherwise, set the build properties for that file to "None" so it won't be picked up, but that means it will be completely ignored when it's time to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

VS/SSDT currently supports interactive tasks with SQL DW but not database projects. See [Database project from Visual Studio to support Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13313247-database-project-from-visual-studio-to-support-azu) and add your votes/comments. Work is in progress to enable this but no ETA just yet. Updates will be posted to that feedback item and the usual Microsoft/Azure notifications channels.